# Cohomology Group

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I am new to the area of cohomology, and I have got stuck on the definition of the abelian group $C_n(G, N)$ of $n$-cochains of $G$ with coefficients in $N$.

I quote here from Anthony W. Knapp's *Basic Algebra* pg. 353:
"$C_n(G, N)$ is the set of all functions into $M$ from the $n$-fold direct
product of $G$ with itself."

It's all okay without this $M$. Should that be $N$ instead?
please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that appears by be a typo.  It should be $N$, not $M$.

You can find the definition of the [cochain complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Cochain_complexes) on Wikipedia to compare.

By the way, Professor Knapp has a list of errata to this book [here](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~aknapp/books/basic-alg/b-alg-corrections11.pdf), which appears to have been updated just yesterday, but this particular typo is not yet included.